# How to upload files >10MB with resumable uploads to Google Bucket using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have an app that successfully uploads videos less than 10MB to a specified Google Cloud Storage Bucket, however, it does not do so is the file is greater than 10MB.

I would like to know how to do this with resumable uploads. I do not want any links to documentation, I have read all of the documentation. It does not help.

I am doing this in python. I understand for me to do a resumable upload I need my authorization token and I have no idea how to do that. So could some one help me with some code?

Here is the code that post Videos <  10MB

```
class GetData(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    data = self.request.get('file')
    bucketname = self.request.get('bucketname')
    typeOf = self.request.get('content_type')
    sender = self.request.get('sender')
    profileVideo = self.request.get('isProfileVideo')
    file_path = ''

    now = time.time()
    objectname = now

    try:
        keytext = open(conf.PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, 'rb').read()
    except IOError as e:
        sys.exit('Error while reading private key: %s' % e)

    private_key = RSA.importKey(keytext)   
    signer = CloudStorageURLSigner(private_key, conf.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                                 GCS_API_ENDPOINT)
    subDirectory = 'videoMesseagesFrom' + sender
    if profileVideo == 'true':
        file_path = '/%s/Profile_Videos/%s' % (bucketname, objectname) 
        r = signer.Put(file_path, typeOf, data)
    else:
        file_path = '/%s/%s/%s' % (bucketname, subDirectory, objectname)
        r = signer.Put(file_path, typeOf, data)


    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'  
    obj = {
               'Completion' : 'Video Successfully uploaded'
               } 
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

I pass in the file and the bucket name. This grabs my credentials from my Google generated key that is in the project and signs a PUT url, then PUTs it for me.

```
def Put(self, path, content_type, data):
    """Performs a PUT request.
    Args:
      path: The relative API path to access, e.g. '/bucket/object'.
      content_type: The content type to assign to the upload.
      data: The file data to upload to the new file.
    Returns:
      An instance of requests.Response containing the HTTP response.
    """
    md5_digest = base64.b64encode(md5.new(data).digest())

    base_url, query_params = self._MakeUrl('PUT', path, content_type,
                                           md5_digest)
    headers = {}
    headers['Content-Type'] = content_type
    headers['Content-Length'] = str(len(data))
    headers['Content-MD5'] = md5_digest
    return self.session.put(base_url, params=query_params, headers=headers,
                            data=data)
```

It is already making a put request with Content-Type headers and all that. Maybe I could put a check on this, so if the file is larger than 10MB somehow edit that PUT method to be a resumable upload, or upload it in chunks. However, I have no idea how to do that.